# What is wrong with this Fortran program?

Tags: fortran, command-line-arguments, fortran90, fortran2003

I can't tell what is wrong with this free form Fortran program. It does not correctly handle its command line arguments.

It works if I use a static array for the command line argument instead of an `allocatable` array.

Also, is this a good first Fortran program? Is this the type of problem for which Fortran would be useful? I already know C, C++, and a little bit of D.

```
module fibonacci
  use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
  implicit none
contains
  subroutine output_fibonacci(ordinal)
    ! Declare variables
    integer, parameter :: LongInt = selected_int_kind (38)
    integer, intent(in) :: ordinal
    integer :: count
    ! integer (kind=LongInt) :: count, compare=2
    integer (kind=LongInt), dimension(2,2) :: matrix, initial
    matrix=reshape((/ 1, 1, 1, 0 /), shape(matrix))
    initial=reshape((/ 1, 0, 0, 1 /), shape(initial))
    count = ordinal
     ! Do actual computations
    do while (count > 0)
       ! If the exponent is odd, then the output matrix
       ! should be multiplied by the current base
       if (mod(count,2) == 1) then
          initial = matmul(matrix, initial)
       end if
       ! This is the squaring step
       matrix = matmul(matrix, matrix)
       count = count/2
    end do
    write (*,*) initial(1,2)
  end subroutine output_fibonacci
end module fibonacci
program main
  use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
  use fibonacci
  implicit none
  ! The maximum allowed input to the program
  integer :: max=200, i, size=20
  character, allocatable :: argumen(:)
  integer :: error, length, input
  allocate(argumen(size))

  ! write(*,*) argcount
  do i=1, command_argument_count()
     call get_command_argument(i, argumen, length, error)
     read(argumen,*,iostat=error) input
     !    write(*,*) argument
     !    write (*,*) input
     if (error .ne. 0) then
        write(ERROR_UNIT,'(I36.1,A)') input, "is not an integer"
        stop (1)
     else if (input > max) then
        write(ERROR_UNIT,'(A,I36.1,A)') "Input ", input, " is too large"
        stop (1)
     end if
     call output_fibonacci(input)
  end do
end program
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line

```
character, allocatable :: argumen(:)
```

declares an allocatable array of characters.  So the statement

```
allocate(argumen(size))
```

makes `argumen` an array of 20 single-character elements.  That's not the usual way of dealing with strings in Fortran and `argumen` doesn't match (in type or rank) the requirements for the second argument in the call to `get_command_argument`.

Instead you should write

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: argumen
```

to declare `argumen` to be a character variable of allocatable length.  In some contexts you can simply assign to such a variable, e.g.

```
argumen = 'this is the argument'
```

without having to previously allocate it explicitly.

With Intel Fortran v14 the call to `get_command_argument` compiles without warning but on execution the argument `argumen` isn't automatically allocated and it remains unassigned.  I'm honestly not sure if this behaviour is standard-conforming or not.  One approach would be to make two calls to `get_command_argument`, first to get the size of the argument, then to get the argument; like this

```
 do i=1, command_argument_count()
     call get_command_argument(i, length=length, status=error)
     allocate(character(length)::argumen)
     call get_command_argument(i, argumen, status=error)
    ! do stuff with argument
    deallocate(argumen)
  end do
```

Using the name `length` for the variable to be assigned the value returned by the optional argument called `length` is legal but a mite confusing.  The `deallocate` statement ensures that `argumen` can be allocated again for the next argument.

I'll leave you the exercise of declaring, and using, an allocatable array of allocatable-length characters.

Disclaimer: the next two paragraphs contain material which some may find subjective.  I will not be entering into any discussion about these parts of this answer.

*Is this a good first Fortran program ?*  It's better than a lot of what I see here on SO.  Personally I prefer the consistent use of the modern `/=` to `.ne.`, `<` to `.lt` (*etc*), I don't use `stop` if I can avoid it (I usually can), and I'm sure I could find other nits to pick.

*Is this the type of problem for which Fortran would be useful?*  Fortran is useful for all types of problem, though I admit it can be quite challenging using it to write a web server.